# Is there a way to have page numbers as alphabets in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

In my rails application I wanted to use pagination for names. I'm fetching the names from a postgresql table.

```
def index
  @users = User.order("name").paginate(:page=>params[:page],:per_page=>50)
end
```

Is there a way of alphabetic pagination that has page numbers as a,b,c..........z

Thanks for your help,
Ramya.

Comment: Messing with `page_number` seems to be the way to go. Do you want the links alphabetic too?

Comment: Yes my requirement is on clicking A it should get me the names starting with A and onclicking another alphabet say C,it should get me the names starting with C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im doing this too in one of my projects. I didnt use a gem for this. Its really easy using Ranges... For example:

```
<% ('A'..'Z').each do |char| %>
     <% if char==params[:char] %>
          <%= link_to :action => 'your_action', :char => char, :class => 'selected_char' %>
     <% else %>
          <%= link_to :action => 'your_action', :char => char %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then in the controller Action you select the Objects by the `params[:char]` given. For example:

```
@instance_var = ModelName.where("field LIKE ?", "#{params[:char]}%")
```

this did it for me. You can easy build a partial out of this and use it for many different Models.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks a lot for answering me. Please help with the contents of the "class=>selected_char"

Comment: You have a list like "a  b  c  d  e..." and you may already have selected one of them so to highlight the currently selected Char I added this class.